# Force a correct max-width

Tags: css

I have the following situation:

```
<div style="max-width:300px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:scroll">
    <a href="#" style="display:block">sometext 1</a>
    ...
    <a ...>...</a>
</div>
```

This is a simplified version, i know how boring it is to read long code :) Now i need to make the div use tne max-width property correctly. I DO NOT NEED CROSS-BROWSER solution - only latest browsers can support it.

The problem:

if there is a space in the A element's content - it will be wrapped right after the space. So in this case "sometext" will be in one line and "1" in another: and that should not wrap until 300px;

If i add "max-width:300px" to the A element - the "1" does not get wrapped, but then the padding is ignored and the number "1" still looks out of bounds when looking at it through firebug.

I don't know if i managed to explain this correctly, but i hope i did.

IF YOU DIDN'T UNDERSTAND THE QUESTION:

I need to make a "popup menu" element with the strucure above so that it would be auto-expanding, but only until 300x200 px. limit is reached.

Thanks for your thoughts

**UPDATE**

It seems opera performs well with this task, but Firefox does not. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QGYwD/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the text in any `a` to wrap, give them a style of `white-space:nowrap`.

http://jsfiddle.net/QGYwD/1/

Comment: I DO WANT the text to wrap as stated in my original post. But only at a correct maximum width.

Comment: Sorry,k but I don't understand what you're getting at. Can you do a screenshot of what goes wrong and what you do want?

Comment: I'll give you a simple example: right-click on the screen and a popup menu appears. That's what i need to do: a popup menu. But it has to be limited in width and height. So if i say that my popup has to be maximum 300 pixels wide - i want the text to wrap only if it's longer than that, but if the text is shorter than 300px - then the entire popup menu should be as wide as text.
In other words - the popup should auto-expand until it reaches 300px and then start wrapping. Don't know how to explain that in a screenshot, sorry.

Comment: Oh, I see what the problem is now. The block does adjust itself to the correct width (the width of the `a` elements), which would be OK, but then it draws a vertical scrollbar, so that the net width is not wide enough, because the width of the scrollbar has been subtracted. Well, yes, that is a problem. I don't have a solution though, yet.

Comment: I'm affraid there's more going on than just the scrollbar problem. Since in all cases that i've tried it either wraps whenever it pleases or doesn't wrap at all. Thanks for trying to help!